# Un adverbe pour « critique »

Tags: adverbes, néologismes, mathématiques, science

Je suis tombé aujourd'hui dans un article de mathématiques en anglais sur l'adverbe *critically*, dans le syntagme « *postcritically finite* ». J'ai cherché une traduction convenable, mais ni *critiquement*, ni le douteux *criticalement* n'existent dans les dictionnaires habituels. Il me semble pourtant qu'il y a une place pour cet adverbe : « Il grandit critique… vite », « elle est allée critique… loin »…

Existe-t-il déjà un tel adverbe que j'aurais manqué, ou me faut-il encore une fois néologir ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Critiquement* est [assez courant](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22critiquement%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr), et mentionné dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/critique) ainsi que le [*Littré*](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/critiquement/17927), mais seulement dans le sens d'*esprit critique*.

Le répertoire des [adverbes de Christian Molinier et Françoise Levrier](http://books.google.fr/books?id=HSHMkiPy4pgC&pg=PA445) ne cite que *critiquement* et *critiquablement* comme adverbe ayant cette racine.

Dans le sens mathématique, *critiquement* est attesté, mais rare. Par exemple [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22critiquement%20instable%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr) ne trouve aucune occurrence de « critiquement instable », mais permet de trouver la [thèse de Sylvain Maginier](http://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/82/06/21/PDF/MAGINIER_Sylvain_1998_opt.pdf) qui utilise ce terme.

On trouve, très rarement, la forme *criticalement*, mais pas dans des publications que je qualifierais de recommandables. *Criticitement* (d'après *criticité*) est introuvable, et de toute façon de construction douteuse.

*Critique* dans son sens scientifique dérive du même mot latin que dans son sens de jugement, l'adjectif *criticus* et ses composés. Il s'agit d'une dérivation plus tardive, mais cela n'empêche pas de construire l'adverbe de la même façon même si on aime s'attarder sur l'étymologie. *Critiquement* suit de nombreux autres adverbes de finale semblable : *uniquement*, *publiquement*, *logiquement*, ...

Je recommande donc l'adverbe *critiquement*.